# Fabric 3.2.2 asks for sudo password when executing NOPASSWD command

Tags: python, django, deployment, fabric

I have configured `sudoers` to let me execute two commands without password:

```
# Allow foobar restart app_server
Cmnd_Alias RESTART = /home/foobar/restart_nginx, /home/foobar/bin/restart_app_server
foobar ALL = NOPASSWD : RESTART
```

When I `ssh` to the server I can execute both commands without password:

```
sudo /home/foobar/bin/restart_app_server
sudo /home/foobar/bin/restart_nginx
```

However when I do the same with Fabric I get the following error:

```
sudo /home/foobar/bin/restart_app_server
sudo /home/foobar/bin/timers_nginx
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
```

This is what my `fabfile` looks like:

```
    conn = Connection(local_settings.FABRIC_HOST, port=local_settings.FABRIC_PORT)
    conn.run(
        f"sudo /home/foobar/bin/restart_app_server && "
        f"sudo /home/foobar/bin/timers_nginx", echo=True)
```

I tried `shell=False`, tried `sudo(...)` instead of `run(...)`. No difference at all. This issue appeared after updating from Fabric 2.x.x to Fabric 3.x.x. But I can use old Fabric 2.x.x. right now.